# How to make UI code dev configurable?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cognito

I have a reactjs app deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment that used Cognito for authentication. I need to make my front-end code DEV configurable using environment variables with database and Cognito.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: Please clarify .. if you want to load the environment variables from database or is it  you want to just run the app with different variables in production.

Comment: @RahilAhmad I want to run the app with different variables in production.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can read any ENV vars from your client side reactjs app, instead you'll need a server side technology to do that. Elastic Beanstalk lets you enter the environment variables for each environment using the management panel. Add your ENV var and these variables will be attached to the `process.env` object

```
const config = {};

config.db = {
  database : process.env.DB_HOST || 'your-db-host'
  database : process.env.DB_USER || 'your-db-user'
  database : process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'your-db-pwd'
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using create-react-app and here is my build script

```
"build": "sh -ac '. ./.env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts build'",
"build:prod": "REACT_APP_ENV=prod npm run-script build",
"build:staging": "REACT_APP_ENV=staging npm run-script build",
```

It requires you to have files like .env.prod and .env.staging files in your root folder to set the environment variables for their respective environments , you can add other scripts as well for example to add something for local environment i would add

```
"build:local": "REACT_APP_ENV=local npm run-script build"
```

In package.json and then add .env.local file in root folder that has my all my local specific env. variables.
Run the build command for CRA as

```
npm run build:local
```

(for build with local env. variables)